# Sent too many emails to myself through workflows, Flagged by MS.

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

I was in the process of creating a custom workflow which involved up to 3 users approving a form submission. For testing purposes, I had all 3 of these users set to myself. After ~2 weeks of working on the workflow, this afternoon I stopped receiving emails.

After investigating the Workflow Health, I found an Non-Delivery Report link to the following: 
[image]

I tried updating one of the emails to a Co-worker, but the email doesn't go through to them either. How can I resolve this and how can I not have it occur in the future?

Comment: can i lol to this ?

Comment: I know I was laughing when it happened xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We faced a similar issue today, all the O365 workflows (sending emails and tasks creation) suddenly stopped working showing the below mentioned error message

(Error: SmtpException while sending email: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. Access denied, tenant has exceeded threshold.)

Our O365 administrator mentioned that 'Microsoft confirmed this is known Service Issue and the Product Group is already engaged and working on a solution'.

Currently our workflows started to work since the last half an hour but we are experiencing delays in workflow execution.

Comment: Any chance you have a link to the MS confirmation?

Comment: Found it: https://twitter.com/Office365Status/status/978667840218701824

Comment: Can confirm this is a current issue also. Should be visible as an entry on the service health dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have end your workflow properly. It seems workflow is loops indefinite time and sends you email

Comment: I've actually started receiving the emails again. I'm not sure what happened, but there was a weird period where it didn't want to send?